# Android Studio Register Link

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created a register link but it doesn't work . I want the "Register Here" link to send me from the login page to the register page . It worked before when I got an answer to my previous question on here but now it's not working for me . Can someone help me ?

Login.java :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);

userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Login register"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="Login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="Register" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_login.xml :

```
<TextView
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register Here"
    android:id="@+id/tvRegisterLink"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `android:onClick="onClick"` from your button and access the onClick from your OnClickListener. You need to choose one of the two methods. You can see them listed well in this answer [Button on click listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323734/android-creation-an-action-from-a-button/30323822#30323822)